# Angular CLI 8 and webpack generates optimized main.js file that is larger than the unoptimized codebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

We are a small team of developers working on a fairly typical ERP system for a customer. We have created hundreds of small input forms, grids, subforms etc. etc., so now we have about 1600 files (.ts, .html) with total size at about 6 MB.

We started from a default SPA .NET Core 2.2 + Angular 6 (upgraded to 8) Visual Studio template and it has been working just fine. 
Except that recently we noticed our build times becoming much slower and our dist package growing up to ridiculous size.

Now our build time is about 25 minutes and most of the time is consumed by ModuleConcatenationPlugin (which seems to be using CPU somewhat inefficiently never going over 15%). **And - surprise! - main.js is 20 MB** (while vendor.js is under 3 MB).

Definitely there's something wrong with the optimization. **Why does our 6 MB TypeScript codebase (with lots of comments and spaces and whatnot) get "optimized" upto a 20 MB file?**

Here are the webpack bundle analyzer results. [image: webpack bundle analyzer results]

As you see, main.js seems clean; there are no foreign code, only our own /src ~1600 files.

**How do we fix the issue, so our code gets properly optimized (and build time reduced, if possible)?**

We aren't doing anything extreme or exotic - it seems a normal use-case; every ERP system would have hundreds of small forms; so why doesn't the optimization work properly out-of-the-box?